# need to convert mp4/avi to usm format

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I have successfully extracted a usm file to a avi video,
by this :`ffmpeg -f mpegvideo -i mainmenu.usm -f avi -q 2 output.avi`
 does anyone know how to convert a mp4 or avi video to a usm file?

Comment: a guy did extract usm to mp4 https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6995

Answer (score 1):

There is only one tool that can convert .avi files to .usm files. It is called Scaleform Video Encoder. [Click here for an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2dVk.png). You can download the tool [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/gjk1ya43ixgx85u/Scaleform+VideoEncoder.zip).